# How to use Semantic UI 'add content' javascript behaviour?

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm trying to initiate a Semantic UI Dimmer with markup like so:

```
<p id="move">Move me</p>

<div class="ui dimmable">

   <h3 class="ui header">
     Overlayable Section
   </h3>

   <div class="ui dimmer"></div>

</div>
```

and js like so:

```
$('.ui.dimmable')
  .dimmer(
    {on: 'click'},
    'add content', $('#move'))
;
```

There is apparently a behaviour called ['add content'](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer.html#/usage) that should detach an element from the DOM and add it into the dimmer.

Does anyone have ideas on how to make this work?

Note - the above does intitiate the dimmer on click of '.ui.dimmable',  I just can't grasp how to use the 'behaviours' Semantic UI Docs mention, and can't find any examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimmer content is black by default, so you need to make your `#move` element white. I tried change it to `h2` with `.ui.inverted.header`

Then you need to add your desired content to your dimmer with this:

```
$(".ui.dimmable").dimmer("add content", $("#move"));
```

And configure it to show on click

```
$(".ui.dimmable").dimmer({
    on: "click"
});
```

[Try it on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytnryf4d/8/)

Comment: Great thanks @NoSoyTsundere - I see that working on JSFiddle.  I should clarify what I'm trying to achieve: The content should be there before the dimmer is open, then move to the dimmer when it is open.  Clicking on that content should not close the dimmer (but clicking outside of the element but in the dimmer should close it).  I've tried opening the dimmer on click of the element I want to move, but then the dimmer will not close on click.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Alright, got that working:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vvogea4/

But do you know if the element can then be replaced to it's original location onClose of the dimmer?  Thanks!

Comment: Righto here we go finally: http://jsfiddle.net/8vvogea4/3/ .  This works as I described in the first comment.